# Component annotation not working in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on a simple spring project which has following code:

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo2;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class AnnotationDemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        Coach theCoach = context.getBean("tennisCoach", Coach.class);
        System.out.println(theCoach.getDailyWorkout());
        context.close();
    }

}
```

**ApplicationContext.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.luv2code.springdemo2"></context:component-scan>
 
</beans>
```

**Coach.java**

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo2;

public interface Coach {
    public String getDailyWorkout();
}
```

**TennisCoach.java:**

```
package com.luv2code.springdemo2;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("tennisCoach")
public class TennisCoach implements Coach {

    @Override
    public String getDailyWorkout() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "Practise your back hand volley daily";
    }

}
```

I am not able to figure out why the error is occurring.

Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:224)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:257)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.luv2code.springdemo2.AnnotationDemoApp.main(AnnotationDemoApp.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/aop/TargetSource
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigUtils.registerAnnotationConfigProcessors(AnnotationConfigUtils.java:157)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser.parse(AnnotationConfigBeanDefinitionParser.java:49)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1371)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:96)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.aop.TargetSource
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 24 more
```

I am using spring version 5 and I have added all the JAR files in the `lib` folder:

[image: spring]

The `applicationContext.xml` file is present at the correct hierarchy, that is, there are no file location error

I am able to use XML based handling but not component annotations.

What is the problem here?

Kindly comment if other information is needed

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `spring-aop-5.3.9.jar`. That's where the class that's reported missing (`org.springframework.aop.TargetSource`) is from, but you only have the sources and javadoc JAR files for `spring-aop`, not the JAR file with the actual classes.

Comment: Can you tell me how to add that? I had downloaded these files from the official spring repo. I don't why this file wasn't included in that.

Comment: You can always find JAR files from mvnrepository.com. In this case, go to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop, select your version, then check the files.